# Passing props to makeStyle in MUI5 (TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I have the following MUI4 code to migrate to MUI5.

under MUI4 I have:

```
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';

type Props = {
  darkMode?: boolean;
};

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    button: (props: Props) => ({
      color: props.darkMode ? '#fff' : '#AE4',
    }),
  }),
);

export default useStyles;
```

rewrite to MUI5:

```
import { makeStyles } from 'tss-react/mui'
import { Theme } from '@mui/material/styles'

type Props = {
  darkMode?: boolean;
};


const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) => ({
  return {
    button: (props: Props) => ({
      color: props.darkMode ? '#fff' : '#AE4',
    }),
  }
})
```

I encounter the error

```
Type 'Props' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.ts(2344)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty well defined in the [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/) how this can be achieved:

```js
const getDesignTokens = (mode: PaletteMode) => ({
  palette: {
    mode,
    ...(mode === 'light'
      ? {
          // palette values for light mode
          primary: amber,
          divider: amber[200],
          text: {
            primary: grey[900],
            secondary: grey[800],
          },
        }
      : {
          // palette values for dark mode
          primary: deepOrange,
          divider: deepOrange[700],
          background: {
            default: deepOrange[900],
            paper: deepOrange[900],
          },
          text: {
            primary: '#fff',
            secondary: grey[500],
          },
        }),
  },
});
```

```
const [mode, setMode] = React.useState<PaletteMode>('light');
const colorMode = React.useMemo(
  () => ({
    // The dark mode switch would invoke this method
    toggleColorMode: () => {
      setMode((prevMode: PaletteMode) =>
        prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light',
      );
    },
  }),
  [],
);

// Update the theme only if the mode changes
const theme = React.useMemo(() => createTheme(getDesignTokens(mode)), [mode]);
```